# What sort of approach should I take for scaling sprites?

Tags: libgdx, sprite

What sort of approach should I take when I'm writing a game that uses sprites.

Say for example, my phone runs with a 1080p resolution. If I wanted to run my game on my phone without some weird stretching going on, would I have to use a large sprite sheet with huge sprites, or would I just write the game with a small sprite sheet, using the original sizes for each sprite (without upscaling), and just let everything be automatically scaled by LibGDX?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend storing the image larger. You could then enable mipmapping and tweak the texture filters. (See [libgdx texture filters and mipmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378791/libgdx-texture-filters-and-mipmap))

This way, the image gets automatically scaled into a variety of sizes on runtime, and then the appropriate image gets selected depending on the size the image is shown.